# Expose components functions in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to implement the following functionality https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/expose-component-functions.html, but I use ES6 syntax

```
@controllable(['center', 'zoom', 'hoverKey', 'clickKey', 'selectedCountry'])
export default class ContactMapView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.initialFunc = this.initialFunc.bind(this);
    }
    initialFunc() { … }
```

When I call initialFunc in my parent class

```
componentDidMount() {
    MapStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange.bind(this));
    this.refs['mapView'].initialFunc();
};
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: this.refs.mapView.initialFunc is not a function
```

Any ideas how could I run function of my child Component?

Comment: I just want to make my child wait for the parent component to mount.

Comment: Please show us the render method for the parent.

Comment: The child will not mount until the parent mounts, so depending on how closely you need to control the ordering, you might be able to simply use `componentDidMount` in the child.

Comment: Your parent render method should have <ContactMapView ref="mapView".../> for that to work.

Comment: Consider switching to arrow function syntax to avoid the explicit bind expression. initialFunc = () => {}
Also refs by strings are deprecated. Please use the callback syntax:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs